# Travel outside Canada during Post-Graduation Work Permit transition period

Tags: working-visas, canada

I am planning to apply for Post-Graduation Work Permit on Jan 15, 2017. And I am considering traveling back to my home country between Jan 20 and Feb 12. My study permit expires in Dec 2017 which is one more year to go.

My concern is what if the work permit gets issued before Feb 11 and I actually have it with me while entering the border, I will only have my study permit. Will it still be valid at that point, or does it become invalid when a post-grad work permit is issued? My Temporary Resident Visa also expires in Dec 2017.

I saw a [post](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/7244/10615) by Mangara asking about the same matter, some answers were about implied status, which I don't think will be a issue for me.

Can anyone help me out please? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same situation as you. I decided to go anyway and I didn't face any problem while coming back to Canada. According to CIC as long as your study permit is valid and you have a valid work permit, this should not be a problem. Your study permit is still valid but make sure you have valid visa too. Without a valid visa a study permit serves no use.

Also, note that [CIC application processing times](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/times/) vary. The chances however are less that you will get a work permit that quickly. Also having a work permit does not make your study permit invalid or something. Study permit and work permits are documents stating that you have valid status in Canada.

*Additionally what you can do is (and I would highly recommend) to get a letter from your college/university stating that you have applied for a post graduate work permit.*

This [answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7244/travel-outside-canada-while-waiting-for-post-graduation-work-permit/7245#7245) by me that you linked, very well answers your question too. The bottom line is that as long as you have a valid study permit and a valid visa, you should not be facing much difficulty.

However you should always contact [CIC customer service](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/contacts/call.asp) and confirm. Number: 1 (888) 242-2100

Comment: One thing I will be risking is if the work permit is finalized before entering the border, I'll need to extend my TRV from student to worker from my home country which leave not enough time to get it from the embassy.

Comment: The work permit is a document received at your current mailing address. If you have a valid study permit and a valid work permit then the TRV doesn't get invalidated for that amount of time. Also when you are returning back to Canada how are you going to have a work permit? This is assuming you put your mailing address in Canada.

Comment: I am gonna use Canada mail addr for sure. So you are saying it wont jeopardize my legal status neither work permit nor study permit, as long as the document and TRV I have are valid?

Comment: Nope. When you enter all they ask is for a valid study permit and a valid TRV. As long as you have that, it should be good. However it all depends on luck. You might get more questions asked if the officer decides to do so. That's when the letter might come in handy.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds more simple and reasonable, and cic officer keeps saying it is your duty to provide proof of all docs and the border remains rights to decide accept or refuse your entry. Sigh...

Comment: Well they are not wrong to tell you the least.

Answer (score 0):

I phoned CIC again this morning, they tell me to bring all the docs proving I am in process of pgwp and my financial fundings that I have enough money to support my stay in Canada.
One more thing worth attention is that once I leave Canada after applying pgwp, I cannot work full time during transition period until granted